# Create wordpress shortcode for jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, shortcode

I Am trying to create a wordpress shortcode that allows users to creat jQuery UI tabs. I found this great script online which claims to do it - however it has some quite unwelcome results in my page.

Firstly, the script I am currently using is as follows:

```
add_shortcode( 'tabgroup', 'jqtools_tab_group' );
function jqtools_tab_group( $atts, $content )
{
    $GLOBALS['tab_count'] = 0;

    do_shortcode( $content );

    if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){
        foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $tab ){
            $tabs[] = '<li><a class="" href="#">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
            $panes[] = '<div class="pane"><h3>'.$tab['title'].'</h3>'.$tab['content'].'</div>';
        }
        $return = "\n".'<!-- the tabs --><ul class="tabs">'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>'."\n".'<!-- tab "panes" --><div class="panes">'.implode( "\n", $panes ).'</div>'."\n";
    }
    return $return;
}

add_shortcode( 'tab', 'jqtools_tab' );
function jqtools_tab( $atts, $content )
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'title' => 'Tab %d'
    ), $atts));

    $x = $GLOBALS['tab_count'];
    $GLOBALS['tabs'][$x] = array( 'title' => sprintf( $title, $GLOBALS['tab_count'] ), 'content' =>  $content );

    $GLOBALS['tab_count']++;
}
```

However, the HTML output I am TRYING to achieve is this:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The shortcode php gives a slightly different output to what I need in order to make this work - here is my current outputted HTML:

```
<!-- the tabs -->
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a class="" href="#">Tab 0</a></li>
<li><a class="" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a class="" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- tab "panes" -->
<div class="panes">
    <div class="pane">
        <h3>Tab 0</h3>Content
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>Content
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, the shortcode I am using looks like this:

```
[tabgroup]

[tab title="tab1"]Content[/tab]

[tab title="tab2"]Content[/tab]

[tab title="tab3"]Content[/tab]

[/tabgroup]
```

My question is, how do I need to change my php code to make the outputted HTML look like the HTML needed to make the tabs work?

Comment: Please ask the question on wordpress.stackexchange.com ,you will get best and quick answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this is what you have to do.

```
if( is_array( $GLOBALS['tabs'] ) ){
    foreach( $GLOBALS['tabs'] as $k=>$tab ){
        $tabs[] = '<li><a href="#tab-'.$k.'">'.$tab['title'].'</a></li>';
        $panes[] = '<div id="tab-'.$k.'"><p>'.$tab['content'].'</p></div>';
    }
    $return = "\n".'<!-- the tabs --><div class="tabs"><ul>'.implode( "\n", $tabs ).'</ul>'."\n".'<!-- tab "panes" -->'.implode( "\n", $panes ).'</div>'."\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also add shortcode like this:-

```
// Tab
function tab_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    return '<div id="tabs-'. sanitize_title( $title ) .'">'. do_shortcode( $content ) .'</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'tab', 'tab_shortcode' );

// Tabs Container
function tabs_container_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    preg_match_all( '/tab title="([^\"]+)"/i', $content, $matche, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

    $tab_title = array();

    if( isset($matche[1]) ) {
        $tab_title = $matche[1];
    }

    $output = '';

    if( count($tab_title) ) {
        $output .= '<div id="tabs">';
        $output .= '<ul class="nav clearfix">';
        foreach( $tab_title as $tab ){
            $output .= '<li><a href="#tabs-'. sanitize_title( $tab[0] ) .'">' . $tab[0] . '</a></li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div>';
    } else {
        $output .= do_shortcode( $content );
    }

    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'tabs_container', 'tabs_container_shortcode' );
```

This will also work for tabs. Hope this will help you bit.